# Understanding observables in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am new to Angular 2 and observables.

I have an HTML template which has a text box. It gets cleared when the observables don't return any data but when data exists it gets filled with the first data item.

I don't know how this happens even though I have read tutorials about observables.

**HTML**

```
<form class="clearfix" role="form"
      [ngFormModel]="basicDetailsForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 no-padding">
        <label for="assignedTo" class="text-muted">Assigned To</label>
        <input class="form-control bold"
               id="assignedTo" 
               type="text" 
               [ngFormControl]="ctrlAssignedTo"
               (change)="assignedToChanged($event)"
               [(ngModel)]="activeItem.assignee.name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

and my component .ts file has

**.component.ts**

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {

            // subscribe to users observable
            this.usersSubs = this.usersSubs || this.itemDetailService.users$.subscribe(function (user: any) {
                if (user.usedFor !== 'basic') {
                    return;
                }

                if (user.id === '0') {
                    context.activeItem.assignee = {};
                    return;
                }

                let assignedTo: any = {
                    id: user.id,
                    type: 'user',
                    url: user.url,
                    name: user.name,
                    archived: false,
                    archiveDate: null
                }

                context.activeItem.assignee = assignedTo;
            });
        }
 constructor(
        @Inject(AppStateService) public appStateService: AppStateService,
        @Inject(ItemDetailService) public itemDetailService: ItemDetailService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        super(appStateService, itemDetailService);


        this.activeItem = this.activeItem || {
            assignee: {}
        };

        // build the form
        this.basicDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'assignedTo': ['']
        });
        this.ctrlAssignedTo = <Control>this.basicDetailsForm.controls['assignedTo'];

    }
```

and my service.ts file has

**.service.ts**

```
 private usersObserver: Observer<any>;

constructor(
    @Inject(ProjectsApiService) private apiService: ProjectsApiService,
    @Inject(AppStateService) private appStateService: AppStateService,
    @Inject(AppObservableService) private appObservableService: AppObservableService) {
    this.activeDetailTab = {
        index: 0
    }
}

public init() {
 this.users$ = this.users$ || new Observable((observer: any) => {
            this.usersObserver = observer;
        }).share();
}

     public getUserByAlias(alias: string, usedFor: string): void {

            let context = this;
            this.apiService.getUserByAlias(alias)
                .subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                    if (data.data.length === 0) {
                        context.usersObserver.next({ id: '0', usedFor: usedFor });
                        return;
                    }

                    data.data.forEach(function (user: any) {
                        context.users.push(user);
                    });

                    data.data[0].usedFor = usedFor;
                    context.usersObserver.next(data.data[0]);
                },
                err => { console.log(err); },
                () => { console.log('Done'); }
                );
        }
```

Comment: Please, provide the part of the code where there's the subscription to the userObserver. With that I can tell you exactly what is happening.

Comment: @DanielPliscki updated the code..pls look into it

Comment: I didn't find any subscriptions to the `userObserver` . only thing i figured out is observable.share()

Comment: You mentioned a text box is being populated with the result. Provide the HTML and the part of the component that controls it. Also, include both constructors of the component and the service.

Comment: @DanielPliscki Thank you for helping me. Updated the code as you have asked for.

Comment: Updated html with form tag and added constructors for service.ts and component.ts files

Comment: If something is not clear, don't hesitate to point out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to explain it to you following the data flow. So let's start with what triggers the flow.

You have an Input which triggers assignedToChanged event whenever something changes.

```
(change)="assignedToChanged($event)"
```

Inside the assignedToChanged() there's a call to the getUserByAlias() method in the service class.

**You have removed this part of the code in your last edit.**

getUserByAlias class apiService.getUserByAlias() and here is where observables step in.

First let's understand what getUserByAlias does. If you know the basics about observables you'll know that .subscribe is called when the api response is returned.
Inside the .subscribe you'll dealing with another observable and we will get there soon. But for now I'll highlight the three main things happening here.

If there's no data in the api response, an object with id: 0 is pushed into the userObservable stream.

```
if (data.data.length === 0) {
    context.usersObserver.next({ id: '0', usedFor: usedFor });
    return;
}
```

Otherwise an array of users is populated with all users returned.

```
data.data.forEach(function (user: any) {
   context.users.push(user);
});
```

And the first user is pushed into the userObserver

```
data.data[0].usedFor = usedFor;
context.usersObserver.next(data.data[0]);
```

Now, notice the userObserver in the above snippets. This observer is the key to notify the textbox. When we call .next() we are pushing a new value into the observable stream and thus, everyone that is listening to this observable will be notified.

But who is subscribed to this observable?
Inside the component, you are subscribing to the userObservable:

```
this.usersSubs = this.usersSubs || this.itemDetailService.users$.subscribe(function (user: any) {
  //implementation removed for readbility
});
```

The function inside .subscribe() will be always called whenever a new value is pushed into the observable stream ( **userObservable.next()** )

The key point is to understand that the service is exposing an observer that any class will be able to listen to and whenever a new value has to be sent, the service will call .next('here goes the value|object').